# difference between 2 environments in R

Tags: r, environment

I have same code I need to execute in R. So, I need to check changes in .GlobalEnv and create new environment, which consists of only new variables or variables, which values were changed via the code.

For example:

```
a <- 5;
b <- 6;
```

After this code execution I need to have "changeEnvironment" environment variable with 2 variables "a" and "b" with values "5" and "6".

Let's execute same other code:

```
b <- 7;
c <- 8;
```

After this "changeEnvironment" must contain only "b" and "c" variables with "7" and "8" values.

What's the best practice for this? And what about speed of this?

Thank you.

Comment: Best practices is this whole way of operating is not a good idea but if you must then `save.image()` can be used to save the current workspace, `rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))` will remove all objects in it and `load("..RData")` will reload the saved image.

Comment: I just noticed there's a package called `track` on CRAN.  It's for tracking objects in environments.  Maybe check that out.

Comment: track looks like what I need.

Comment: In my last comment `..RData` should have only one dot: `.RData`